# How to increase padding value in an inline style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to increase padding value using its previous value, something like this:

```
const newListItemStyle = {
    ...listItemStyle,
    paddingRight: listItemStyle.paddingRight + '50px',
}
```

How can i do something like this ?

Comment: You can read `selector.style.paddingRight`, trim off the unit and convert to a number, then add 50 and tack the unit back onto the end. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: `listItemStyle.paddingRight + 50 + 'px',` but only if paddingRight is number or string with only number and not e.g. "10px" then you will need to use `parseInt`

Comment: @jcubic Doesn't work, please note that `paddingRight` itself has `px`

Comment: @cjl750 Yes, exactly what i want, can you give me an example

Comment: @AliAhmadi edited just after you added yours comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseInt` to get the number part first. Then add `50` to get the sum. Then add `"px"` to convert it to a string

```js
const newListItemStyle = {
    ...listItemStyle,
    paddingRight: parseInt(listItemStyle.paddingRight) + 50 + 'px'
}
```

Comment: @AliAhmadi make sure to read up on the second param to `parseInt` (radix) if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Adiga's answer will help you with simple operations like `'50px' + '50px'`, but for a more bulletproof answer that will take into effect varying units (or even no units) and allow for decimal places, you would be better off avoiding `parseInt`.

Instead you can use a regular expression that will match numbers and possibly a decimal point and then convert that to a number using the `Number()` function, which won't round it like `parseInt()` would.

The logic of determining how much extra padding to add and what the unit on that should be I leave to you.

```
const newListItemStyle = {
    ...listItemStyle,
    paddingRight: Number(listItemStyle.paddingRight.match(/[\d\.]+/g)) + 50 + 'px'
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed this is a more complete answer mostly because in some cases the value is not integer which parse int will not work, but for simplicity's sake i will let Adiga's answer remain as the accepted one, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @AliAhmadi if it has decimals, you can use [**`parseFloat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)